# Woocommerce settings effect on page layout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

when I set woocommerce setting for shop to display categories. the layout is ugly yet when the same setting is display products.the layout is fine. how can I have a good layout with display categories option set?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to display categories among the products in the archive view.
If that is the case, you should use the `content-product_cat.php` template in `wp-content/plugins/woocomemrce/templates/`. Copy this template into your theme's `woocommerce` folder(create it if it does not exist).